# Odoo 10 - Api.multi decoration doesn't loop to all records

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo-10

I'm new in creating module In Odoo from scratch and I'm reading this book: **Odoo 10 development essentials - Daniel Reis**. Following the book, step-by-step, I created this simple class:

```
# coding: utf8
from odoo import models, fields, api


class TodoTask(models.Model):
    _name = 'todo.task'
    _description = 'to-do task'
    name = fields.Char('Description', required=True)
    is_done = fields.Boolean('Done?')
    active = fields.Boolean('Active?', default=True)


    @api.multi
    def do_toggle_button(self):
        for task in self:
            task.is_done = not task.is_done
        return True
```

Next is the xml file for views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_form_todo_task" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">To-Do Task Form</field>
        <field name="model">todo.task</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="To-Do task">
                <header>
                    <button name="do_toggle_button" type="object" string="Toggle Done" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button name="do_clear_done" type="object" string="Clear All Done"/>
                </header>
                <sheet>
                    <group name="group_top">
                        <group name="group_left">
                            <field name="name"/>
                        </group>
                        <group name="group_right">
                            <field name="is_done"/>
                            <field name="active" readonly="1"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record id="view_tree_todo_task" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">To-Do Task Tree</field>
        <field name="model">todo.task</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="To-Do task shown">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="is_done"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record id="view_search_todo_task" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">To-Do Task Search</field>
        <field name="model">todo.task</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search>
                <field name="name"/>
                <filter string="Not Done" domain="[('is_done','=',False)]"/>
                <filter string="Done" domain="[('is_done','!=',False)]"/>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

For the do_toggle_done method, the book says: "*The code loops through all the to-do task records and, for each one, modifies the field, inverting its value*." This is because with api.multi, if I understand correctly, the object "self" represents all the recordset, but when I call the function (with push button) it only modifies  the flag of the record that I am modifying and the others remain unchanged. There is something wrong? Are I having misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have added the multi function on form view, you will get only one record on self. Self represents a dataset but in form view this data set have only one record. If you want to toggle all the tasks done state you can use either a wizard that will call a **@api.model** function to query all the tasks and process it accordingly or use a **ir.server.action** like

```
  <record id="ir_actions_server_timesheet_sheet" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="sequence" eval="5"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_hr_timesheet_current_open"/>
        <field name="code">action = model.open_timesheet()</field>
        <field name="condition">True</field>
        <field name="name">My Timesheet</field>
    </record>
```